# How to add a lattice on cube's surface?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I made a single lattice around a cube in the following way:

1. Added a cube on scene.
2. In Edit mode I added loopcut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
3. Removed corner vertices.
4. Converted the cube to curve.
5. In Object Data tab I changed geometry properties and received next object:

[image: Single lattice]

Now I need to make double lattice like this(left side):

[image: Double lattice]

But when I made double lattice by previous way I have got object shown in the right side of previous picture.
How can I get a required object?
May be exists better way to make this objects?

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the wireframe modifier or the skin modifier:

For Wireframe modifier:

- Add Cube
- Subdivide with 2 divisions
- delete edge vertices
- add wireframe modifier

For skin modifier:

- Add Cube
- Subdivide with 2 divisions
- delete edge vertices
- delete all faces (faces only!)
- apply skin modifier
- Scale with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>